# Getting duplicate rows by several columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I'm trying to search duplicate rows by several columns in large table (near 18 000 rows). Problem is that queries take a lot of time, I tried this:

```
 SELECT * FROM table_name a, table_name b 
 WHERE a.col1 = b.col1 
 AND a.col2 = b.col2 
 AND a.col3 = b.col3
 AND a.col4 = b.col4 
 AND a.id <> b.id
```

and this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name 
WHERE col1 IN (
    SELECT col1 
    FROM table_name 
    GROUP BY col1 
    HAVING count(col1) > 1
    )
AND col2 IN (
    SELECT col2
    FROM table_name 
    GROUP BY col2
    HAVING count(col2) > 1
    )
AND col3 IN (
    SELECT col3
    FROM table_name 
    GROUP BY col3
    HAVING count(col3) > 1
    )
AND col4 IN (
    SELECT col4
    FROM table_name 
    GROUP BY col4
    HAVING count(col4) > 1
    )
```

they both work, but too slow. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't get why Siphon's try with `group by having count >1` doesn't work for you. Can you post sample data and desired result?

Comment: He wanted each row to be returned. The group by will give you a duplicate, but not the other identical row(s). So if 4 rows are grouped together, then only 1 will be returned with the group by. This wouldn't work for everyone, and at least not for him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using one joint GROUP BY statement like:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
    GROUP BY col1, col2, col3, col4
    HAVING count(*) > 1
```

At the very least, it will look cleaner.

**EDIT**

To return all results as a sub-set for the previous column:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name 
WHERE col4 IN (
  SELECT col4
  FROM table_name 
  WHERE col3 IN (
    SELECT col3
    FROM table_name 
    WHERE col2 IN (
      SELECT col2
      FROM table_name
      WHERE col1 IN (
        SELECT col1
        FROM table_name
        GROUP BY col1
        HAVING count(col1) > 1
        )
      )
    )
```

This, in concept, should give you all results in a faster execution time.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it don't solve my task. I need those duplicates, but not group them.

Comment: My mistake. It sounded like you want to see IF there are duplicates rather then return all results.

Comment: The only other suggestion I would have is to use sub-queries, reducing the total results as you match columns. So, match col1, then match col2 from results of col1. This will prevent the need to match all 18000 rows for every column.

Comment: See my edit for what I mean. You can make this run faster if you target columns known not to have as many duplicates first. So, the furthest nested select should have the fewest possible duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for reply man, i tried, but it's not working at all, it freezes for a endless loop. I tried "lite" version of this query - select duplicates by one column, but it not working too, very strange - SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 IN
(SELECT col1 FROM table GROUP BY col1 HAVING count(col1) > 1)

Comment: This is strange. The nested query in my edit was adapted from your second original example, just with nested SELECT statements instead of the AND conditionals. Try looking for any typos or keyword conflicts.