# finding similar records in mysql

Tags: mysql

OK guys this is my problem , I have a database table  with "fname, lname, mname" fields
I can find duplicates on each field but I want to duplicates in all 3 fields or similar to take account of type O's

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have many records?

Comment: Check out this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367742/getting-duplicate-rows-by-several-columns-in-mysql).

Answer (score 0):

If I get your mean correctly, you can use the following:

select * from tablename a, tablename b where a.lname=b.lname and a.fname=b.fname and a.mname=b.mname

Where tablename is under the check table. I tested it in My sql.